# Implicit conversion between reference types

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Given two classes A and B that have the same data layout (ie only the functions differ, not the members), how can one make the reference types implicitly convertible?

```
struct Storage
{
    uint32_t a, b;
};


class First : private Storage
{
    int32_t GetA() { return a; }
    int32_t GetB() { return b; }
};

class Second : private Storage
{
    int64_t GetA() { return a; }
    int64_t GetB() { return b; }
};


void FuncF(const First& first);
void FuncS(const Second& second);    

// I would like to be able to call like
int main()
{
    First f;
    Second s;

    FuncF(s);          // Conversion fails
    FuncS(f);          // Conversion fails

    return 0;
}
```

I can get the above working for pass-by-copy, also if I use inheritance like `class First : Second` I can get the conversion working one way.

(Note the above is a contrived example, you could imagine the int32_t and int64_t returns types to be more complex classes that can be constructed from uint32_t).

To be clear: I'm not interested in a work-around, I specifically want to be able to bind a `First` object to a `Second` reference and vice versa, relying on the fact the data is the same.

```
FuncS(static_cast<Second&>(f));   // This works, is it standard (ie portable) 
                                  // and can I define the class so the cast is not necessary?
```

Comment: You could make the inheritance public, then values of both types can be bound to references to the base.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Type Conversion Operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr383.htm)

So Second will need a member function of the form: Second::operator First();
Likewise in First as well. This will do implicit conversion with no need to type-cast.